# I can't import player relative controls in unity

Tags: unity

I'm developing a mobile game in Unity 5 but I can't find player relative control asset anywhere.Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It is called the Character Controller (I think this is what you are asking).

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html